# Why does the section תָּנוּ רַבָּנָן in the siddur contain two elements not apparently relating to sacrifices?

Tags: prayer-book, korban, korbanos-ketores-prayers

In the section of the [siddur](http://www.onlinesiddur.com/shac/) dealing with the sacrifices, after the parsha of the spice offering, there is a section from the gemoro (Kereisos 6a) that deals with the spice offering starting with the words

> תָּנוּ רַבָּנָן פִּטּוּם הַקְּטרֶת כֵּיצַד

Then a little later there seems to be an insertion of the following text which does not obviously relate to the sacrifices

> ג"פ - ה' צְבָאות עִמָּנוּ מִשגָּב לָנוּ אֱלהֵי יַעֲקב סֶלָה:  ג"פ - ה'
>   צְבָאות אַשְׁרֵי אָדָם בּוטֵחַ בָּךְ:  ג"פ - ה' הושִׁיעָה הַמֶּלֶךְ
>   יַעֲנֵנוּ בְיום קָרְאֵנוּ:  אַתָּה סֵתֶר לִי מִצַּר תִּצְּרֵנִי רָנֵּי
>   פַלֵּט תְּסובְבֵנִי סֶלָה:

This is then followed by some more material appropriate to the order of the sacrifices that starts

> אַבַּיֵּי הֲוָה מְסַדֵּר סֵדֶר הַמַּעֲרָכָה

and then there seems to be another interposition of the prayer that starts:

> אָנָּא בְּכחַ גְּדֻלַּת יְמִינְךָ תַּתִּיר צְרוּרָה:

which does not obviously relate to the sacrifices.

So why does the section 
תָּנוּ רַבָּנָן
contain two elements not apparently relating to sacrifices?

Comment: What Nusach are you looking at (or is this found in multiple)?

Comment: Ashkenaz, Sefard and Edus Hamizrach (I don't have access to other nuschaos).

Comment: Fwiw, I don't think of them as part of the "_Tanu rabanan_" section but as following it.